# Google AdWords claiming my site has an “existing compromise that prevents referrer URLs from successfully visiting the site through an ad”

Tags: redirection, uri

Here's the email I just received from Google about why they won't turn on my AdWords account after my hosting provider had DNS issues which caused AdWords to believe the site was compromised by malware:

> The destination URL: http://www.ledsignage.com/counters-clocks-timers is returning a 404 error when our systems scan it via an ad click. This indicates that the site's server likely has an existing compromise that prevents referer URLs from successfully visiting the site through an ad. Please note that the URL may still work when directly visited in a browser since the referer URL is a completely different setting.

Is this actually possible? There's no other way to reach the page other than using the URL to it. I thought a referrer URL is in the header of the HTTP request, and simply stored the URL of the page you were just at.

Are they saying that there's some kind of malware on my site that's filtering requests based on the value of the referrer URL? Have any of your ever had this problem?

I had to comment out the following lines to get the .htaccess file to work with goaddy:

```
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
#php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
#php_flag register_globals                 off
#php_flag session.auto_start               off
#php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
#php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
#php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
```

I am having another issue but only with some pages. I'll probably make this another question, but it might be related. Some pages are causing redirect loops. Here are some examples:

http://www.ledsignage.com/faq, /software, /outdoor (stackexchange won't let me put in more than one link)

I've tried to remove the url alias from these pages and still have the infinite redirect issue. I did recently move this site from another hosting provider to godaddy. This is drupal 7.2. I'm not sure what other info you need so just let me know and I'll post a comment with the information (assuming I can commment). Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: wow, I never seen like this link http://www.ledsignage.com/faq

Comment: Drupal 7.2 is damn old. Current release is 7.24, 22 minor versions younger. Have you considered update? Big chance it was already fixed inone of these updates.

Comment: If GoDaddy won't host a Drupal site properly (i.e., you have to take necessary config out of .htaccess just to get the site to work), you need to move to another host. Or at least contact their support for advice. I'm not sure we're going to be able to help you here, as this screams of server config

Comment: @Clive I don't think it's GoDaddy issue. OP have `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.ledsignage.com/faq'">` in his HTML. GoDaddy used to modify HTTP headers (or that's what I heard), but I never heard that it modify client's HTML. It must be something OP did, module he installed etc.

Comment: @Mołot Wow, I never even thought to look at the HTML, putting a meta refresh of 0 in is a bizarre thing to do. cmzmuffin, remove that refresh tag and the problem will go away. I still think you should move to a proper hosting provider, though.

Comment: Well, at least some of the problems. Still some elements (like http://www.ledsignage.com/sites/default/files/Deloitte%20Counter%20on%20Stand.png ) took over 18 seconds to load. Long enough for Google to think site has problems.

Comment: I'm not able to find that tag within the content itself, it must be getting there from a module. I'm doing a full text search on the codebase to find that.

Comment: Try searching for `drupal_add_html_head()`...

Comment: I found the problem. My last host must have added pages to deal with their DNS issues, so they created pages like faq.htm and so forth, and the htaccess file thinks it's ok because those pages exist. I deleted those files and now those pages are working. Hopefully that's what google was complaining about.

Comment: @cmzmuffin well, consider posting this as a self-answer. But also consider talking with your host about slow loading times... It would be a waste to pay for ads if people would get irritated and go away before page loads.

Comment: I had to clear the cache, and now I'm seeing immediate page loads. Maybe I just have good internet I don't know, but pages are loading up for me instantly.

Comment: @cmzmuffin as you can see on my screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6h0s.png some of http requests fails to get properly closed even if site appears to be loaded instantly. Data is there, but browser never gets end of data marker. It is a hosting issue that may be problematic sometimes.